# "Put together" or "assembled" for a book?

Tags: word-choice

I'm collecting information about Structure from the net and textbooks. Since I paid too much effort on this, I'm going to make it a book(ish), for studying purposes. But I couldn't decide on whether I should use

> Put together by X

or

> Assembled by X

on the book. I feel like *put together* fits more, but again, I'm not sure. Which one should I use? Also is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use *compiled*.

> [compile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compile): 1. to compose out of materials from other documents. 2.  to collect and edit into a volume.

Comment: I rather like this term for this purpose.  There is no insinuation of authorship.  I would probably add *edited* to it.  *Compiled and edited by . . .*

Answer (score 0):

You might consider **collate**, which has the meaning of organizing and editing as well as collecting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **[edited](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/edit) by**

> to produce a book by choosing, arranging, and explaining things that other people have written

In the US, the person in charge of creating a compilation is regularly called the *editor*. This is especially true when material has been excerpted, shortened, selected from a larger unit, or modified in any way.